# Getting number of stories/issues in each status at a certain point in time with JIRA Rest + JQL

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

Using created will only grab the stories that were created in the time frame specified. How do I grab issues that existed in a certain status 2 - 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [POST /api/2/search](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest) REST resource to run your JQL query. It takes a body like:

```
{
    "jql": "project = HSP",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 15,
    "fields": [
        "summary",
        "status",
        "assignee"
    ],
    "fieldsByKeys": false
}
```

This JQL query will return issues that were changed to status "In Progress" between 3 and 2 weeks ago:

```
project = PROJ AND status CHANGED TO ("In Progress") AFTER -3w BEFORE -2w
```

This JQL query will return issues that were in status "In Progress" between 3 and 2 weeks ago:

```
project = PROJ AND status WAS IN ("In Progress") AFTER -3w BEFORE -2w
```

For more info, check the JQL documentation:

- [WAS IN operator](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-WAS_INWASIN)
- [CHANGED operator](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-CHANGEDCHANGED)